# Align equation while centering symbol

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

Consider this situation:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    & \bigwedge_{a'\in\mathcal{A}} \text{ some text goes here}\\
    & \bigwedge_{a':a'>a} \text{ and here} \\
    & \bigwedge_{a':a'<a} \text{ and here}
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

this results in the following:

[image]

By looking at the image it should be already clear what is my aim :)
I would like the lines to be aligned while the `\bigwedge` being centered.

I tried using `array` instead but the result doesn't look really the same (the `\bigwedge` symbol looks smaller, while I would like to retain the same look of the `equation` context)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{rcl}
    & \bigwedge\limits_{a'\in\mathcal{A}} & \text{ some text goes here}\\
    & \bigwedge\limits_{a':a'>a}    & \text{ and here} \\
    & \bigwedge\limits_{a':a'<a}    & \text{ and here}
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to turn your code snippets into an MWE, just to make everything that little bit smoother

Comment: Sure, here it is!

Comment: Thank you :) (I already Upvoted, but an MWE is a good way to get others to as well)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

I only slightly change/simplify your MWE ...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
    \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}cl}
\bigwedge\limits_{a'\in\mathcal{A}} & \text{some text goes here}\\
\bigwedge\limits_{a':a'>a}          & \text{and here} \\
\bigwedge\limits_{a':a'<a}          & \text{and here}
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** with added `\displaystyle` the `\bigwedge` is thew same as in simple equation. For adding this option the package `array` is added into preamble of MWE.

Comment: Thanks but my complaints about `array` is that it slightly changes the look of `\bigwedge` (looks smaller). I should probably be more clear in the OP, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `\smashoperator` command, from `\mathtools`. Also, `\colon` has a better horizontal spacing than `:`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    & \smashoperator{ \bigwedge_{a' ∈ \mathcal{A}}} \text{some text goes here} \\
    & \smashoperator{\bigwedge_{a'\colon a'>a}} \text{and here} \\
    & \smashoperator{⋀ _{a'\colon a'<a}} \text{and here}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]